# what is the name of the process that runs .gitlab-ci.yml file in gitlab server?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to find out the process and the user that executes the `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration file on gitlab repository.

the reason I want to findo out is bercuase in gitlab configuration yaml file under scripts section the it runs scp commands that does the copy of source file to mount path of docker container and then next link under scriupts start docker container.

all this was setup by previous developer who has now left..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the user who executes the runner is the one which will execute the yaml commands.

In my case, I am using an shell executor which runs as `gitlab-runner`.

Comment: so does that mean the user is the one thats also running the gitlab server ? or could it be different ?

Comment: That would definably be a different user as its running on the actual gitlab host as opposed to the runner which is running on the target host. It may help for your to add a few debug commands in your script: whoami, pwd, env|sort . This has helps me figure out what going on during CI pipeline

Comment: So I echoed whoami, I see its gitlab-runner .